# array_column and foreach, performance wise which is better?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I am curious about performance of php function array_column as compared to regular foreach loop. 
In my case I want to get single column data from db table into array. My query results ~10k to ~50k records, so should I go with regular foreach loop or array_column is better here?

Comment: why not test it urself ??

Comment: Definitely `fetchAll`...

Comment: `array_column` is much faster, though in terms of human perception, the difference is negligible for small datasets. i always use array column over foreach unless i need to extract multiple columns. technically, `for` is faster than `foreach` as well since you are not ever modifying the array's internal pointer.

Comment: @Andrew, Yes I have tested this and concluded to foreach is faster. But I was curious, if they add some inbuilt function then how it can be slower than manual function.

Comment: @Abhijeet: Well your test was faulty.

Comment: @Abhijeet:  Dunno.  I tested with 50K rows with 26 columns each and `array_column()` was always faster.

Comment: In general, Native array functions are always faster than foreach. Though i know one case when you are making several function call from inside of native array function it was bit slow. But i will put it like it all depends on what kind of data and scenario you are considering for bench mark.

In general from fastest to slowest -> SPL Iterators->native array functions -> foreach

Comment: Thanks @JimitShah for explanation.

Comment: @AbraCadaver https://progblog.net/2014/08/array_column-performance-of-built-in-functions/ 
This claims otherwise.. Even I'm getting same results as the blog.

Comment: #1 Well look in the comments of that page https://3v4l.org/n9dsU.  #2 that's a small array, check: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/082ad76af0c8d3a2ea4d82612893ab8314c11d97 It varies but array_column() is normally faster.

Comment: If I have an array with IDs and I have to check if an ID is within the array, it would be faster if array is sortered?

Answer (score 5):

Since `array_column` is a built-in function, it would probably be fastest one. Hence my tests also showed `array_column` is %50 faster than a foreach loop.

Comment: In my dataset with 2000 columns over 5 arrays with 30 rows each (60k data points), I'm getting a 3x speed increase.  800ns (foreach) to 260ns (array_column).