# Without using a loop, how can I "chop" an array of associative arrays into separate arrays, grouped by keys?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, key

Say I have the following array of associative arrays:

```
$MasterArr = array(
    array("food" => "apple", "taste" => "sweet"),
    array("food" => "lemon", "taste" => "sour"),
    array("food" => "steak", "taste" => "meaty")
);
```

**Without** using a `foreach` loop, is there a way that can I "chop" it into 2 different arrays whose values come from the same keys, so it looks like this:

```
$FoodArr = array("apple","lemon","steak");
$TasteArr = array("sweet","sour","meaty");
```

Comment: Just to say: At the end you will always loop through your array. If you now see it in your written code or not.

Comment: @Nitin I like to minimize lines of code where I can, so I had a feeling there was some 1-liner way to do this

Comment: implemetation of [array_column](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

Comment: @user3163495 Did not know that array_column() is faster than foreach. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319318/array-column-and-foreach-performance-wise-which-is-better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for that:

```
$FoodArr = array_column($MasterArr, 'food');
$TasteArr = array_column($MasterArr, 'taste');
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo in the question. I'll mark this as answer after 10 mins (SO making me wait)

Answer (score 3):

For `PHP < 5.5.0`, you can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$FoodArr = array_map(function($v){ return $v['food']; }, $MasterArr);
$TasteArr = array_map(function($v){ return $v['taste']; }, $MasterArr);
```